# Auslander-Reiten translate of toric vector bundles

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, rt.representation-theory

By the result of A. Klyachko, there is categorical equivalence of toric vector bundles i.e. t-equivariant vector bundles on toric varieties and filtered vector spaces. For instance, on a toral surface, toric vector bundle of rank $2$ correspond to decreasing $\mathbb{Z}$-filtrations of two dimensional vector space $V$ on the join of three armed quiver, and on each ray we get one dimensional spaces up to certain length.

My question is the following: is it possible to interpret this filtered vector spaces as a quiver representation Q with a particular orientation? And, if it is possible, what would be Auslander-Reiten translate of toric vector bundle? And then, can we consider $\tau$-exceptional vector bundles as a generalization of exceptional vector bundles introduced by Rudakov and his school?

This question is not valid in general, because Auslander-Reiten translate is possible only for coherent sheaves over projective curves. But in the case of toric vector bundles, there might be an exception which I am looking for.